I was sacked from a nursery for children for gross misconduct due to safe guarding (child welfare) concern. Will this be on my next DBS check in UK?
I used to work in nursery. I was sacked for gross misconduct for a safeguarding issue. The issue was referred to the Local Authority Designated Officer, Ofsted and the Disclosure and Barring Service (DBS).
I now need an enhanced DBS check; will it be on there?

Two comments about your question.  1) You are using acronyms that a lot of people here will not know. 2) Related to #1, is that we don't know your location, and anything related to employment typically is dependent on your location.

My location is in the UK. I was with the company for years, and then someone wrote an safeguarding allegation and for reported to ofstead, LADDO and DBS

VTC - As much as I wish you good luck here - this is several layers deep in some very very extensive Law. We are not Lawyers and the fact that multiple regulatory bodies are involved means that this question needs to go to someone familiar with the Law in the UK surrounding this.

Clearly not to do with plants

@TheDemonLord While I'm not going to hammer this open I have to disagree, DBS checks in particular are common enough in UK hiring that many who work (or hire) in relevant sectors will have knowledge on what is and isn't included. Asking about challenging a DBS decision (or similar) would be crossing into legal advice territory

And for God's sake change your user name to something that can't identify you!!

@MarkRotteveel 100% agree it is almost identical

Absolutely 100% yes. The entire point of a DBS check is to be aware of incidents which need to be considered when someone may be placed in a position of trust over children (or vulnerable adults).
Make sure you have a very, very, very good explanation for your potential future employer as to what happened and why you should be trusted in future.

Thankyou, I wasn’t notified that it was going to be on my DBS?

I recommend you talk to a lawyer or Citizens Advice. You are in way over your head right now.

@PhilipKendall I would suggest this comment is so important it should be added to your answer!

@Charlottehockings DBS themselves will likely contact you (if they haven't already) asking for "representations" (i.e. your side of the story) and ultimately with the outcome of the referral. Regardless of outcome the referral itself says on your Enhanced DBS Check.

This happened years ago but they haven’t contacted me. This week I have been asked about an enhanced DBS check so I didn’t know if anything could be on there since I have never been contacted that was all.

Stop replying to this question. Start contacting Citizens Advice. I can't put it any more simply than that.

There are four kinds of Disclosure and Barring Service (DBS) checks:

a basic check, which shows unspent convictions and conditional
cautions
a standard check, which shows spent and unspent convictions and
cautions
an enhanced check, which shows the same as a standard check plus any
information held by local police that’s considered relevant to the
role
an enhanced check with barred lists, which shows the same as an
enhanced check plus whether the applicant is on the list of people
barred from doing the role

(Information taken from https://www.gov.uk/dbs-check-applicant-criminal-record)
The DBS exists pretty much solely to provide this kind of information to employers of people who will be working with all kinds of vulnerable people. If they are holding information about you, I would expect it to come out on a check however reading this information it may depend on if they are conducting an Enhanced Check or and Enhanced Check with Barred Lists. Either way, the advice given in other comments is correct - either consult an employment lawyer or get an appointment with Citizens Advice immediately. This is too important to trust the word of strangers on the internet with.
Also, if your user name for StackExchange is anything like your real name, you may want to consider changing it. Anyone Google searching your name (as I would do for any new potential employees) would find this thread.

The first thing would be to get the information relevant for a DBS check. To do this, you will need to submit two requests:

Request a copy of your criminal record, by asking for a "basic DBS check" (Request a basic DBS check).
The "standard" and an "enhanced" DBS Check may supply an employer with additional information, in particular whether you are on a "barred list". To request this information, you must Make a subject access request to DBS.

Note that the "enhanced" DBS check may also contain information held by local police. You cannot request this information from the DBS However, you can use a "subject access request" to find out whether such information was supplied by DBS in the past. You may also be able to find this information by directly asking local police services.
If there is an entry about the safeguarding issue, you at least know where you stand. If you believe the entry is unjustified, you can fight it (see e.g.
Report a problem about a criminal record check or barring decision). However, that is a different (probably complex) problem.
If you choose to accept the entry, you will then have to find out which jobs will (and are allowed to) still accept you. Consider asking a new question, once you know what your entry says.
Finally, as the other answers explain, this is a complex subject, so you should probably get qualified help, such as Citizens advice or legal assistance.
Includes info supplied by motosubatsu, Philip Kendall

Unfortunately it isn't quite this simple - a Basic check wouldn't show many things that would turn up on an Enhanced one and a safeguarding referral such as the OP's, even if not raised to the level of being criminal would be such a thing.

@motosubatsu: Thanks, added to my answer.

@motosubatsu: By the way: Is there no way to get the complete data the DBS has on you and may return for checks? It seems rather Orwellian that the DBS may have information on you that it will tell potential employers, but not tell you personally.

@sleske You can make a subject access request.

@PhilipKendall: thanks, added

@sleske As Philip says the only real option is an SAR -  that will get you what data the DBS has on you - it's not quite the same as what they'd provide as the result of a check (e.g. it won't include any criminal record info) but it's probably close enough for most purposes. Particularly since you can get the criminal record portion by doing a basic check on yourself and then combine the two.

@motosubatsu: Yes, as I wrote in my answer (the two bullets) - basic DBS check + subject access request. You'll still miss the "information held by local police", though. Seems you need to collect that separately with each police authority.
